# Can't join Server 2003 domain with XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, windows-server-2003

I installed windows server 2003 on my laptop using vmware and also installed xp pro using vmware on my desktop pc ..
I have setup a domain using the Server 2003 wizard but when I try to set up the XP machine to join the domain (called ABCD.edu), I get "A domain controller for the domain ABCD could not be contacted." how i can fix this problem?

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/ this site is mostly programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10 hours of searching and testing I solved this Problem.

This Problem can Happens for 2 reasons :

1- Bridge Problem.. before installing Windows Server you should check the Network adapter in vmware and
I prefer check customize then choose "vm0" if your connection is wired then in advanced setting choose the NIC that the "vm0" will take.

2- Firewall problem... Not only windows firewall but even the firewall of anti virus you have.. in my situation I have Bitdefender internet Security 2015 and when i Disabled its firewall, The problem solved directly.

Comment: Good, Anyway that was the basic things you should do while using vmware environment. You dont need to disable the antivirus firewall, instead add an exception to allow specific traffic required. Thats the best practice to be followed in any network environment. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether both the virtual machines are having same ip address range like

```
Server IP address : 192.168.1.1
subnet : 255.255.255.0, 
gateway 192.168.1.1,
dns 192.168.1.1

Client xp ip address 192.168.1.10, 
subnet 255.255.255.0, 
gateway 192.168.1.1 
and dns 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Yeah all configurations are true but still same problem